# Getting back to main ViewController of the Tab Bar after moving between tabs

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am developing an iOS app in Swift 2.3, XCode 8.0. My app has 4 tabs and to each of the tabs - 4 different View Controllers are connected. Inside the 4 View Controllers I have embedded Navigation controllers.

My requirement is that when a user selects tab 1 -> goes to ViewController 1 -> Next the user can go to 2nd  View Controller as there is a navigation controller.
But when the user selects the second tab and then comes back to the first tab, instead of showing the first View Controller that is directly attached to tab 1, the View Controller that was last opened with the back button is shown.
How can I move directly move to the View Controller attached to the first tab?

Answer (score 0):

The embedded navigation controller should automatically keep track of the stack for you regardless of which tab the user is in with the tab bar controller. Make sure each tab has its own navigation controller embedded into it instead of having the entire tab bar controller embedded in one navigation controller.

For example, if you implemented this programmatically:

```
    let viewController1 = UIViewController()
    let navigationController1 = UINavigationController()

    navigationController1.setViewControllers([viewController1], animated: true)

    let viewController2 = UIViewController()

    let tabBarController1 = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController1.setViewControllers([navigationController1, viewController2], animated: true)
```

Here the navigationController1 will keep track of which viewController is on top of the stack regardless of where the user is in the tab bar controller.

Comment: I have implemented the connection between ViewControllers, NavigationsController and TabController in the StoryBoard and not programmatically. So how do I come to the Parent View Controller from the Child View Controller on changing tabs. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the solution -

This works for me - 
In my main tab bar viewController, I made it a delegate of both `UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate` and then implemented the `didSelectViewController` method of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` as below -

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    let index : Int = (tabBarController.viewControllers?.indexOf(viewController))!

    let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController
        navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

}
```